Bazel macro in dependency module using source files from remote module
I have a repo (openscad_3d_objects, https://github.com/roleroz/3D_objects) which uses some rules for running openscad for creating 3D models through bazel that I'm trying to release (openscad_rules, https://github.com/roleroz/openscad_rules). In openscad_rules I have a macro to create a unit-test for these 3D models, and that macro creates an sh_test() rule that uses source files from the openscad_3d_objects repo (in this case the ones used for libs:cylinder_section_test) and the source files in openscad_rules, which are needed to define the test
I'm having issues to reference the files in the macro, my original attempt used //path/to:file to access the files, and that fails with
23:16:38:(main):~/git/3D_objects $ bazel build libs:cylinder_section_test
ERROR: no such package '@@openscad_rules~//libs': BUILD file not found in directory 'libs' of external repository @@openscad_rules~. Add a BUILD file to a directory to mark it as a package.
ERROR: /home/joso/git/3D_objects/libs/BUILD:20:10: no such package '@@openscad_rules~//libs': BUILD file not found in directory 'libs' of external repository @@openscad_rules~. Add a BUILD file to a directory to mark it as a package. and referenced by '//libs:cylinder_section_test'
ERROR: Analysis of target '//libs:cylinder_section_test' failed; build aborted: Analysis failed
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.243s, Critical Path: 0.00s
INFO: 1 process: 1 internal.
ERROR: Build did NOT complete successfully

The source file for this macro can be found at https://github.com/roleroz/openscad_rules/blob/bff15af70c6618caa8b71825a9e98e25f4fa40a3/scad.bzl#L89
In this error it looks like bazel is looking for the referenced files under the openscad_rules module, but they clearly don't exist there, as those are part of the caller (openscad_3d_objects)
My second attempt used @@openscad_3d_objects//path/to:file to access the files, and that fails with
23:32:17:(main):~/git/3D_objects $ bazel build libs:cylinder_section_test
DEBUG: /home/joso/.cache/bazel/_bazel_joso/be502dc84f0632ae63335fed148f9feb/external/openscad_rules~/scad.bzl:130:10: @@openscad_3d_objects//libs:cylinder_section_test
DEBUG: /home/joso/.cache/bazel/_bazel_joso/be502dc84f0632ae63335fed148f9feb/external/openscad_rules~/scad.bzl:130:10: @@openscad_3d_objects//libs:hardware_test
DEBUG: /home/joso/.cache/bazel/_bazel_joso/be502dc84f0632ae63335fed148f9feb/external/openscad_rules~/scad.bzl:130:10: @@openscad_3d_objects//libs:hollow_cylinder_test
ERROR: no such package '@@openscad_3d_objects//libs': The repository '@@openscad_3d_objects' could not be resolved: Repository '@@openscad_3d_objects' is not defined
ERROR: /home/joso/git/3D_objects/libs/BUILD:20:10: no such package '@@openscad_3d_objects//libs': The repository '@@openscad_3d_objects' could not be resolved: Repository '@@openscad_3d_objects' is not defined and referenced by '//libs:cylinder_section_test'
ERROR: Analysis of target '//libs:cylinder_section_test' failed; build aborted: Analysis failed
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.061s, Critical Path: 0.00s
INFO: 1 process: 1 internal.
ERROR: Build did NOT complete successfully

The source file for this macro can be found at https://github.com/roleroz/openscad_rules/blob/289e3f1cc3d571ec331e2df1b2189804d72131ee/scad.bzl#L89
In my second error, it seems like it's looking for the files in the correct module, but in the context of openscad_rules, which doesn't know of the caller (openscad_3d_objects)
My bazel version is 7.2.1
How am I supposed to reference those files in the macro?
Thanks
Joso

Bazel is quite strict about only using what you pass in. e.g. for what Bazel calls 'tools', you'll still need to specify those as attributes for rule inputs (for more info on this example, see here).
In this case, if you're wanting to reference a target in @@caller_repo//path/to:file, then you need to pass that target in as an input. In this case, you might add a parameter to your macro like libs, which you expect to be a package with specific libs.
I will add, IMO, a better design is to specify each specific lib as a parameter, rather than assume a specific layout in a libs package. This is not advisable - just pass these deps in as labels and let Bazel work for you. The same goes for other things you're getting relative to that. Just pass in everything you need as parameters.
